# Как вывести определённые предложения из текста в новый файл в Python?

Tags: python-3.7

Требуется разбить текст на предложения и заменить в нём Обаму на Трампа, выбрать предложения с президентом и записать в файл.

Попытался решить следующим образом, но не получается корректно задать условие:

***Код:***

```py
var = open('ObamaToTrump.txt', mode = 'r')
varString = var.read()
var.close()
varString = varString.replace("Obama","Trump")
varString = varString.replace("Barack","Donald")
varString = varString.replace("Mr.","Sir")
varString = varString.split('[.!?\n]')
if 'Trump' in 'ObamaToTrump.txt':
    fileToWrite = open('ObamaToTrump!.txt', mode = 'w')
    fileToWrite.writelines(varString)
```

***Текст:***

```html
Obama’s Secret to Surviving the White

Not since Lincoln has there been a president as fundamentally shaped — in his life,
convictions and outlook on the world — by reading and writing as Barack Obama.
Last Friday, seven days before his departure from the White House, Mr. Obama
sat down in the Oval Office and talked about the indispensable role that books have
played during his presidency and throughout his life — from his peripatetic and
sometimes lonely boyhood, when “these worlds that were portable” provided
companionship, to his youth when they helped him to figure out who he was, what
he thought and what was important.
During his eight years in the White House — in a noisy era of information
overload, extreme partisanship and kneejerk
reactions — books were a sustaining
source of ideas and inspiration, and gave him a renewed appreciation for the
complexities and ambiguities of the human condition.
“At a time when events move so quickly and so much information is
transmitted,” he said, reading gave him the ability to occasionally “slow down and
get perspective” and “the ability to get in somebody else’s shoes.” These two things,
he added, “have been invaluable to me. Whether they’ve made me a better president
I can’t say. But what I can say is that they have allowed me to sort of maintain my
balance during the course of eight years, because this is a place that comes at you
hard and fast and doesn’t let up.”
The writings of Lincoln, the Rev. Martin Luther King Jr., Gandhi and Nelson
Mandela, Mr. Obama found, were “particularly helpful” when “what you wanted was
a sense of solidarity,” adding “during very difficult moments, this job can be very
isolating.” “So sometimes you have to sort of hop across history to find folks who
have been similarly feeling isolated, and that’s been useful.” There is a handwritten
copy of the Gettysburg Address in the Lincoln Bedroom, and sometimes, in the
evening, Mr. Obama says, he would wander over from his home office to read it.
Like Lincoln, Mr. Obama taught himself how to write, and for him, too, words
became a way to define himself, and to communicate his ideas and ideals to the
world. In fact, there is a clear, shining line connecting Lincoln and King, and
President Obama. In speeches like the ones delivered in Charleston and Selma, he
has followed in their footsteps, putting his mastery of language in the service of a
sweeping historical vision, which, like theirs, situates our current struggles with race
and injustice in a historical continuum that traces how far we’ve come and how far
we have yet to go. It’s a vision of America as an unfinished project — a continuing,
morethantwocentury
journey to make the promises of the Declaration of
Independence real for everyone — rooted both in Scripture and the possibility of
redemption, and a more existential belief that we can continually remake ourselves.
And it’s a vision shared by the civil rights movement, which overcame obstacle after
obstacle, and persevered in the face of daunting odds.
Mr. Obama’s long view of history and the optimism (combined with a stirring
reminder of the hard work required by democracy) that he articulated in his farewell
speech last week are part of a hardwon
faith, grounded in his reading, in his
knowledge of history (and its unexpected zigs and zags), and his embrace of artists
like Shakespeare who saw the human situation entire: its follies, cruelties and mad
blunders, but also its resilience, decencies and acts of grace. The playwright’s
tragedies, he says, have been “foundational for me in understanding how certain
patterns repeat themselves and play themselves out between human beings.”
Context in Presidential Biographies
Context in Presidential Biographies
Presidential biographies also provided context, countering the tendency to think
“that whatever’s going on right now is uniquely disastrous or amazing or difficult,”
he said. “It just serves you well to think about Roosevelt trying to navigate through
World War II.”
Even books initially picked up as escape reading like the Hugo Awardwinning
apocalyptic scifi
epic “The ThreeBody
Problem” by the Chinese writer Liu Cixin, he
said, could unexpectedly put things in perspective: “The scope of it was immense. So
that was fun to read, partly because my daytoday
problems with Congress seem
fairly petty — not something to worry about. Aliens are about to invade!”
In his searching 1995 book “Dreams From My Father,” Mr. Obama recalls how
reading was a crucial tool in sorting out what he believed, dating back to his teenage
years, when he immersed himself in works by Baldwin, Ellison, Hughes, Wright,
DuBois and Malcolm X in an effort “to raise myself to be a black man in America.”
Later, during his last two years in college, he spent a focused period of deep selfreflection
and study, methodically reading philosophers from St. Augustine to
Nietzsche, Emerson to Sartre to Niebuhr, to strip down and test his own beliefs.
To this day, reading has remained an essential part of his daily life. He recently
gave his daughter Malia a Kindle filled with books he wanted to share with her
(including “One Hundred Years of Solitude,” “The Golden Notebook” and “The
Woman Warrior”). And most every night in the White House, he would read for an
hour or so late at night — reading that was deep and ecumenical, ranging from
contemporary literary fiction (the last novel he read was Colson Whitehead’s “The
Underground Railroad”) to classic novels to groundbreaking works of nonfiction like
Daniel Kahneman’s “Thinking, Fast and Slow” and Elizabeth Kolbert’s “The Sixth
Extinction.”
Such books were a way for the president to shift mental gears from the briefs
and policy papers he studied during the day, a way “to get out of my own head,” a
way to escape the White House bubble. Some novels helped him to better “imagine
what’s going on in the lives of people” across the country — for instance, he found
that Marilynne Robinson’s novels connected him emotionally to the people he was
meeting in Iowa during the 2008 campaign, and to his own grandparents, who were
from the Midwest, and the small town values of hard work and honesty and
humility.
Other novels served as a kind of foil — something to argue with. V. S. Naipaul’s
novel “A Bend in the River,” Mr. Obama recalls, “starts with the line ‘The world is
what it is? men who are nothing, who allow themselves to become nothing, have no
place in it.’ And I always think about that line and I think about his novels when I’m
thinking about the hardness of the world sometimes, particularly in foreign policy,
and I resist and fight against sometimes that very cynical, more realistic view of the
world. And yet, there are times where it feels as if that may be true.”
Writing was key to his thinking process, too: a tool for sorting through “a lot of
crosscurrents in my own life — race, class, family. And I genuinely believe that it was
part of the way in which I was able to integrate all these pieces of myself into
something relatively whole.”
A Writer of Short Stories
Mr. Obama taught himself to write as a young man by keeping a journal and
writing short stories when he was a community organizer in Chicago — working on
them after he came home from work and drawing upon the stories of the people he
met. Many of the tales were about older people, and were informed by a sense of
disappointment and loss: “There is not a lot of Jack Kerouac openroad,
young kid
on the make discovering stuff,” he says. “It’s more melancholy and reflective.”
That experience underscored the power of empathy. An outsider himself — with
a father from Kenya, who left when he was 2, and a mother from Kansas, who took
him to live for a time in Indonesia — he could relate to many of the people he met in
the churches and streets of Chicago, who felt dislocated by change and isolation, and
he took to heart his boss’s observation that “the thing that brings people together to
share the courage to take action on behalf of their lives is not just that they care
about the same issues, it’s that they have shared stories.”
This lesson would become a cornerstone of the president’s vision of an America
where shared concerns — simple dreams of a decent job, a secure future for one’s
children — might bridge differences and divisions. After all, many people saw their
own stories in his — an American story, as he said in his keynote address at the 2004
Democratic National Convention possible “in no other country on Earth.”
In today’s polarized environment, where the internet has let people increasingly
retreat to their own silos (talking only to likeminded
folks, who amplify their
certainties and biases), the president sees novels and other art (like the musical
“Hamilton”) as providing a kind of bridge that might span usual divides and “a
reminder of the truths under the surface of what we argue about every day.”
He points out, for instance, that the fiction of Junot Diaz and Jhumpa Lahiri
speaks “to a very particular contemporary immigration experience,” but at the same
time tell stories about “longing for this better place but also feeling displaced” — a
theme central to much of American literature, and not unlike books by Philip Roth
and Saul Bellow that are “steeped with this sense of being an outsider, longing to get
in, not sure what you’re giving up.”
Mr. Obama entered office as a writer, and he will soon return to a private life as
a writer, planning to work on his memoirs, which will draw on journals he’s kept in
the White House (“but not with the sort of discipline that I would have hoped for”).
He has a writer’s sensibility — an ability to be in the moment while standing apart as
an observer, a novelist’s eye and ear for detail, and a precise but elastic voice capable
of moving easily between the lyrical and the vernacular and the profound.
He had lunch last week with five novelists he admires — Dave Eggers, Mr.
Whitehead, Zadie Smith, Mr. Diaz and Barbara Kingsolver. He not only talked with
them about the political and media landscape, but also talked shop, asking how their
book tours were going and remarking that he likes to write first drafts, long hand, on
yellow legal pads.
Mr. Obama says he is hoping to eventually use his presidential center website
“to widen the audience for good books” — something he’s already done with regular
lists of book recommendations — and then encourage a public “conversation about
books.”
“At a time,” he says, “when so much of our politics is trying to manage this clash
of cultures brought about by globalization and technology and migration, the role of
stories to unify — as opposed to divide, to engage rather than to marginalize — is
more important than ever.”
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте это:

```py
import re


with open('input.txt') as f:
    text = f.read()

text = text.replace("Obama", "Trump").replace("Barack", "Donald").replace("Mr.", "Sir")

sentences = re.split(r'[.!?\n]', text)

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for sentence in sentences:
        if 'Trump' in sentence:
            f.write(sentence + '\n')
```